# Multiple IF conditions in one formula

Tags: excel, if-statement, google-sheets, conditional-statements

Hi I'm new to Excel from google sheets. I was able to do this in google sheets ok but having trouble trying to figure out Excel. I want to put all of this into one formula.

```
=IF(AND(B50="Buy",C50="Call"),FILTER(Sheet1!S6:S31,(Sheet1!U6:U31=E50)*((Sheet1!Q6:Q31=A50)*((Sheet1!R6:R31=C50)))))
    =IF(AND(B50="Buy",C50="Put"),FILTER(Sheet1!S6:S31,(Sheet1!U6:U31=E50)*((Sheet1!Q6:Q31=A50)*((Sheet1!R6:R31=C50)))))
    =IF(AND(B50="Sell",C50="Call"),FILTER(Sheet1!T6:T31,(Sheet1!U6:U31=E50)*((Sheet1!Q6:Q31=A50)*((Sheet1!R6:R31=C50)))))
    =IF(AND(B50="Sell",C50="Put"),FILTER(Sheet1!T6:T31,(Sheet1!U6:U31=E50)*((Sheet1!Q6:Q31=A50)*((Sheet1!R6:R31=C50)))))
```

Excel help window corrected the above code to the snippet below, but getting "Value" errors. Each query works separately fine, just an issue with the ,'s and )))'s when I put them all together.

```
=IF(AND(B50="Buy",C50="Call"),FILTER(Sheet1!S6:S31,(Sheet1!U6:U31=E50)*((Sheet1!Q6:Q31=A50)*((Sheet1!R6:R31=C50,
IF(AND(B50="Buy",C50="Put"),FILTER(Sheet1!S6:S31,(Sheet1!U6:U31=E50)*((Sheet1!Q6:Q31=A50)*((Sheet1!R6:R31=C50,
IF(AND(B50="Sell",C50="Call"),FILTER(Sheet1!T6:T31,(Sheet1!U6:U31=E50)*((Sheet1!Q6:Q31=A50)*((Sheet1!R6:R31=C50,
IF(AND(B50="Sell",C50="Put"),FILTER(Sheet1!T6:T31,(Sheet1!U6:U31=E50)*((Sheet1!Q6:Q31=A50)*((Sheet1!R6:R31=C50))))))))))))))))))))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You putted bracket incorrectly. Try-

```
=IF(AND(B50="Buy",C50="Call"),FILTER(Sheet1!S6:S31,(Sheet1!U6:U31=E50)*(Sheet1!Q6:Q31=A50)*(Sheet1!R6:R31=C50)),
IF(AND(B50="Buy",C50="Put"),FILTER(Sheet1!S6:S31,(Sheet1!U6:U31=E50)*(Sheet1!Q6:Q31=A50)*(Sheet1!R6:R31=C50)),
IF(AND(B50="Sell",C50="Call"),FILTER(Sheet1!T6:T31,(Sheet1!U6:U31=E50)*(Sheet1!Q6:Q31=A50)*(Sheet1!R6:R31=C50)),
IF(AND(B50="Sell",C50="Put"),FILTER(Sheet1!T6:T31,(Sheet1!U6:U31=E50)*(Sheet1!Q6:Q31=A50)*(Sheet1!R6:R31=C50)),""))))
```

Comment: @codebreaker If it works then please accept the answer (tick mark it) to treat the thread as solved.